# Terraform module override problem. The module updates the value every time

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file, terraform-modules

I have use case where a particular module will run over again. The usecase is as follows:

I have created a resource called google_compute_firewall. Then I called this resource via module. This module will take input related to firewall from a yaml file. For the first time when I run the module, it will create a FW but when I try to run the same module with another FW configuration, it will delete the previously created FW.

This means every time I want to create a Firewall I need to create a new module. So for 500 requests there will 500 module and this makes no sense. Is there a better option that I can explore?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Why do people enjoy down voting questions? This Portal is to ask question that other guy doesnt know. Either help or move forward

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear, but you may be looking for the addition of meta-arguments in Terraform 0.13 to iterate over a module declaration.

Comment: To be honest what I wanted to convey was that if I have a module that is provisioning firewall deployment, I will pass parameters to the module. Then I run apply command and the firewalls are deployed. Now I cannot use the same module to create another firewall with different parameters. It will try to destroy the old firewall and create a new firewall with new parameters.  And that I didnt want so I thought how is industry reusing the same module over different parameters

Comment: Are you running locally on a CI/CD environment? My guess is that you are running locally. On rerun, the state is getting overridden & as a result, the old resources too got destroyed. 

If you persist the state elsewhere & on each rerun, you point to a new path for state file persistence, you will not hit the issue. 

By no means, this is the problem of modules. Modules offer reusability but state persistence is the job of the calling function sourcing the module..

Answer (score 1):

Terraform doesn't work that way your executing it. When you add a module to the configuration and then executes it. It creates that state. If you remove that module it will remove it when it gets executed. If you change it. It changes on execution. Now for your case you want to keep the first module, and then add a second module for the next set up.